# C++ STD::find_if using structure predicate

Tags: c++

```
 key_struct kStruct;
 kStruct.x = 2;
 std::find_if(m_cueCommands.begin(), m_cueCommands.end(), find_MyInt(kStruct));

 struct key_struct
 {
   int x;
   string y;
   string z;
 }

 struct find_myInt : std::unary_function<key_struct, bool>
 {     
    int  x;     
    find_myInt(key_struct kStruct):myInt(kStruct.x){}     
    bool operator()(key_struct const& m) const
    {         
     return m.x == myInt;     
    }
 };
```

I am pretty sure I have this a bit messed up but, I think it is moderatly close. What I am trying to do I have the key_struct as the key in my map. I would like to be able to search the keys and return the information that I setup the key_struct with. If I set the key_struct with x  = 2 then I only want to return where the int x is equal to 2. If I set where x = 2 and y = "testString" then I would like to return only the subset of values where x  = 2 and y = "testString".

I believe my approach is close but, I think I am missing something. Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you always want to compare with x? Or only if x != 0?

Btw, there seems to be an error in your struct constructor: there is no member named `myInt`, thus it should be: `find_myInt(key_struct kStruct) : x(kStruct.x){}`. But that doesn't matter, it needs to be changed anyway.

Here's what I would try. This is untested, might contain errors and the "calculation" of the boolean return value is extremely inefficient. Anyway...

To use it, create a struct you want to match with, as you can see from the code, it will only try to match if `x > 0, y != "" and z != ""`. So if you set the "search" struct to `x = 5, y = "" and z = ""`, it will match every key for which `x == 5` (y & z can be whatever).

```
typedef std::pair<key_struct, your_value_type> yourMapType;

struct find_myStruct : std::unary_function<key_struct, bool>
{
  private:
    key_struct myStruct;

  public:
    find_myInt(key_struct const & kStruct): myStruct(kStruct) {}

    bool operator() (yourMapType const & m) const
    {
      bool result = true;

      if (myStruct.x > 0)
        result &= (myStruct.x == m.first.x);

      if (myStruct.y != "")
        result &= (myStruct.y == m.first.y);

      if (myStruct.z != "")
        result &= (myStruct.z == m.first.z);

      return result;
    }
};
```

**[Edit]** Noticed you want to use a map, so I update the code accordingly. Still very much untested, feel free to point out errors.

**[Edit 2]** In case you have problems actually creating the map, because you don't have strict weak ordering on your key_struct, then this should do.

Again, untested, might contain errors. Also pretty inefficient with all the `if`'s, but well... feel free to get them out with your favourite Karnaugh map solver ([BMin](http://code.google.com/p/bmin/) comes to mind).

```
struct cmp_key_struct
{
  bool operator() (key_struct const & lhs, key_struct const & rhs) const
  {
    bool result = (lhs.x < rhs.x);

    if ((!result) && (lhs.x == rhs.x))
    {
      result = (lhs.y < rhs.y);

      if ((!result) && (lhs.y == rhs.y))
        result = (lhs.z < rhs.z);
     }

     return result;
  }
};

std::map<key_struct, your_value_type, cmp_key_struct> yourMap;
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use `find_if` on a map. If you are trying to use the struct as a map key, as you said, you need a comparison that provides "[strict weak ordering](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/StrictWeakOrdering.html)". Use "<" instead of "==", for instance. Then provide that comparison to the map. Or overload the `<` operator in your struct. You can use the `[]` operator or the `find()` method of `map` to do O(log n) searches, where `find_if` is O(n).

Comment: This applies for example to `binary_search` or `lower_bound` but not to `std::find_if` which does a linear search.

Comment: `find_if` expects an equality relation, not a strict weak ordering.

Comment: Note that the OP said, "What I am trying to do I have the key_struct as the key in my map." `map` requires strict weak ordering.

Comment: @Fred: at least from the looks of things, he *should* be using `std::map`, but is actually using `map` more generically to describe what he's doing, not talking about an actual `std::map` object.

Comment: The ordering has nothing to do with his problem. It seems the OP already has a map, so I'm guessing the strict weak ordering is dealt with. He want to match on a partial key.

Comment: The struct given provides no strict weak ordering, and therefore cannot be used as a map key. The OP is vague on what the actual problem is, so I'm guessing that's it.

Comment: @Jerry: You might be right. I hadn't thought of that interpretation of the question.

Comment: @Jerry: Correct, as I suggested in my answer. But that requires strict weak ordering, which the given comparator does not provide.

Comment: Sorry -- I should have reread your answer before pointing that out.

Comment: I put a strict weak ordering function in my answer. Assuming the OP actually wants to use that struct as key and has some value to pair it with.

Answer (score 0):

This is corrected version :

```
 struct find_myInt : std::unary_function<key_struct, bool>
 {     
    int  myInt;     /// HERE
    find_myInt(key_struct kStruct):myInt(kStruct.x){}     
    bool operator()(key_struct const& m) const
    {         
     return m.x == myInt;     
    }
 };
```