# In C++, how to use find_if on a map with a functor when keys are struct with strings?

Tags: stl, dictionary, c++

I have a `stl::map` which key type is a custom struct. I want to know if this map already has a key with a specific string as component (noted as "id" below), whatever the value of its other components. Inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8054223/597069) answer and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5717389/597069) one also, I try to use `stl::find_if` with a custom `functor`:

```cpp
map<myStruct, vector<size_t> > myMap;

struct myStruct
{
  string a, b, c, id;
};

struct checkId : unary_function<pair<myStruct, vector<size_t> >, bool>
{
private:
  string _exp;
public:
  checkId (myStruct x) : _exp(x.id) {}
  bool operator() (const pair<myStruct, vector<size_t> > & p) const
  {
    return p.first.id.compare(_exp) == 0;
  }
};

map<myStruct, vector<size_t> >::iterator it;
myStruct newS;  // to be initialized, but not shown here
it_mP2P = find_if(myMap.begin(), myMap.end(), checkId(newS));
```

When I compile this, gcc returns me:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_function.h: In member function ‘bool std::less<_Tp>::operator()(const _Tp&, const _Tp&) const [with _Tp = myStruct]’:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_map.h:347:    instantiated from ‘_Tp& std::map<_Key,_Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::operator[](const _Key&) [with _Key = myStruct, _Tp = std::vector<long unsigned int, std::allocator<long unsigned int> >, _Compare = std::less<myStruct>, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const myStruct, std::vector<long unsigned int, std::allocator<long unsigned int> > > >]’
myprogram.cpp:386:    instantiated from here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_function.h:227:  error: no match for ‘operator<’ in ‘__x < __y’
```

Does this mean that I have to overload the operator "<" to work with my custom struct if I want to use my functor "checkId"? How can I do this? I am not a C++ expert,so thanks in advance for any piece of code.

Comment: It looks like you need `operator<` (or a custom predicate) in order to create the map using myStruct as key. Nothing to do with find_if.

Comment: hint: http://codepad.org/n7yWIRnQ  It has nothing to do with your functor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://codepad.org/VYNqdZeF

```
struct myStruct
{
  std::string a, b, c, id;
  bool operator<(const myStruct& rhs) const //HERES THE MAGIC
  {return id < rhs.id;}                     //WHEEEEEEEEEEEE!
};
```

This is required to make `std::map<myStruct, stuff>` work, without passing a custom comparison functor.

Comment: Thanks! By the way, is "rhs" supposed to stand for something? Because it's not the first time I see it.

Comment: `LHS < RHS`  are "Left Hand Side" and "Right Hand Side" respectively.

Answer (score 1):

It's got nothing to do with checkId. The following demonstrates the same problem:

```
map<myStruct, vector<size_t> > myMap;

struct myStruct
{
  string a, b, c, id;
};
```

`std::map` is a *sorted* map (it's usually implemented as a binary search tree)... the key type (`myStruct` in this case) must have `operator<` implemented simply to construct the map.

If you don't need fast lookups, you can just use a `vector< pair< myStruct, vector<size_t> > >`; if you need fast lookups, you have to add *some* kind of structure to `myStruct`. For a `std::map` this must be a comparison operator; alternatively you can use a `std::unordered_map` (in C++11; this is usually implemented as a hash table) -- in this case you will need to implement a hash function.

See the documentation of `std::map` and `std::unordered_map` for more details.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with your use of `find_if`.

For a type to be a key of a map, it needs to be comparable, either by implementing operator< or by providing a comparator as a template parameter of the map.

Answer (score 0):

Mooing Duck's answer is the easiest to do, but not the most flexible

if you go and write

```
struct myStruct
{
  std::string a, b, c, id;
  bool operator<(const myStruct& rhs) const
  {return id < rhs.id;}                    
};
```

then all your maps that have `myStruct` as a key, will have to be sorted
by `id`.

Suppose you have one map that needs to be compared by `a`, and another one by `b`. If you put `operator<()` inside your `myStruct`, then you will have coupled the struct with its users, tightly, which is not good programming practice.

Instead, you could set a compare function to each map:

```
struct myStruct
{
  std::string a, b, c, id;   // keep your struct unchanged, and independent of clients
};

bool Compare_by_a(const myStruct &s1, const myStruct& s2)  {
  return s1.a < s2.a;
}                    

bool Compare_by_b(const myStruct &s1, const myStruct& s2)  {
  return s1.b < s2.b;
}                    

bool Compare_by_id(const myStruct &s1, const myStruct& s2)  {
  return s1.id < s2.id;
}                    

map<myStruct, vector<size_t>, Compare_by_a > map1;
map<myStruct, vector<size_t>, Compare_by_b > map2;
map<myStruct, vector<size_t>, Compare_by_id > map3;
```